# What is the better place to implement SQL Transaction?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

What is the better place to implement SQL transaction?

1. Within application program's business logic or
2. In side stored procedure?

Is it a bad practice to open SQL transaction within the business logic code?

when we are handling complex business logic such as a batch process?

Please explain me what is the best way and why?

Comment: Should post this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman Why? It is on-topic here.

Comment: The transaction should span any operations which should be grouped into a transactionally atomic unit of work.  There is no universal best practice or single answer, it depends on the logic being implemented and how error conditions should be handled.

Comment: It's a very broad question. There are several good reasons for both attempts, so it mainly it depends on your application and environment. Maybe you explain what you have, then we can make better suggestions.

Comment: @Patrik Hofman: See the comment by Patrik Eckebrecht, that's why it is a good choice to *not* post this here

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman I find, it is ok here. It is too broad, yes, but not misplaced.

Comment: This question needs to be narrowed down to a more specific usecase. As it stands now the only real answers are "my opinion is" or "it depends" and we already have two of the first and one of the other. Voting to close as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: This is definitely *not opinion-based*, but it is too broad. Different options apply to different scenarios. An ETL job can't use transactions inside stored procedures. A complex stored procedure that has to succeed or fail can't depend on external transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion first of all: in Stored Procedure.

In SP very simple using transactions, example (MS SQL 2008R2)

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE P_MyProcedure
 AS
 BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    BEGIN TRY 

    select 'Do someting here' 

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END
    END CATCH;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION; 
END
```

Then you can safely write the business logic. And bother about the transaction on other levels, if you wish.

Comment: Unless of course you want to run two procedures in one transaction, or execute an ETL job, or if you are using an ORM. In fact, *not* catching an exception will actually rollback the transaction *and* terminate a session. By catching you allow other code to continue as usual. Individual INSERT/DELETE statements are atomic anyway so they don't need  transactions simply to make them safe

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it depends on whether the transaction should cover multiple calls or not. If the transaction should be done over exact one call to the database, you could opt to keep the transaction inside the procedure. (Note that when running one statement over ADO.NET in SQL Server they are already packed in a single transaction)

If you need to do multiple calls, using the same transaction, you could pull it client-side, or create a procedure that calls the underlying procedures for you.

Comment: I need to do multiple calls and I have implemented as you said. Thanks for your opinion